# Transfer data to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to create a new worksheet, name that sheet based on the value of cell in another sheet (i.e. `sheet1.Range("F3").value`).

After that I need to go to another sheet in the same workbook where my data is located, select certain data and transfer it to the new sheet.

This is the code I use to create the new sheet and name it.

```
sub createNewSheet()

    sheet_name_to_creat = sheet1.range("F3").value

    for rep = 1 to (worksheets.count)
        if lCase(Sheets(rep).name = Lcase(Sheet_name_to_create) Then
            MagBox "This Sheet already exists"
            exit sub
        end if
    next

    Sheets.add after:=sheets(sheets.count
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).name=Sheet_name_to_create

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare worksheet variables and put your data sheet and your newly added sheet into them. Then it's easy to manipulate data on either one.

```
Sub createNewSheet()

    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    'Rename this sheet to the name of the sheet where your data is located
    Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MyDataSheet")

    sheet_name_to_create = Sheet1.Range("F3").Value

    For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
        If LCase(Sheets(rep)).Name = LCase(Sheet_name_to_create) Then
            MagBox "This Sheet already exists"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = Sheet_name_to_create
    Set wsNew = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'Now grab the data from your data worksheet
    Dim myData As String
    myData = wsData.Range("A1").Value

    'Then put it in your newly added sheet
    wsNew.Range("A1").Value = myData

    wsData = Nothing
    wsNew = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a few edits to the above statement to make it more effective. I know the changes are minor but this should work.

```
Sub createNewSheet()

    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    'Rename this sheet to the name of the sheet where your data is located
    Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MyDataSheet")

    sheet_name_to_create = Sheet1.Range("F3").Value

    For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
        If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(Sheet_name_to_create) Then
            MagBox "This Sheet already exists"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    Set wsNew = Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    wsNew.Name = Sheet_name_to_create

    wsData.Range("A1:Z80").copy  'Change range here to whatever range you need to move to the new sheet
    wsNew.Range("A1").pastespecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats  

    wsNew = Nothing

End Sub
```